# Как сделать семиугольник (heptagon) в svg

Tags: html, css, svg, inkscape

Мне очень нужно сделать svg семиугольник, но я плохо разбираюсь в svg и в интернете не нашёл готового кода. Помогите пожалуйста примером или описанием способов, как его сделать.

Comment: Приветствуем вас на ru.stackoverflow. Векторный редактор Inkscape можно скачать на [официальном сайте](https://inkscape.org/ru/)  Редактор бесплатный, можно выбрать русский интерфейс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь векторным редактором, например Inkscape

1. На панели инструментов выберите: **Рисовать звёзды и многоугольники**, далее выберите опцию  **7 вершин** и растягивая мышкой из центра нарисуйте семиугольник.
   При этом нужно следить, чтобы контуры семиугольника не вышли за границы документа (серая рамка)
2. Сохраните файл
3. Оптимизируйте его, чтобы убрать лишнюю служебную информацию Inkscape с помощью [SVGOMG](https://svgomg.net/)
4. Изменить размеры семиугольника можно с помощью `width height` в шапке svg файла

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400" height="400" width="400" version="1.1">
  <path d="m200.8 21 138.1 66.5 34.1 149.4-95.6 119.8-153.3 0L28.6 237 62.7 87.5Z" style="fill:none;stroke-width:4;stroke:#f11a00"/>
</svg>
```